# Универсальный метод для грамотного вывода существительных в зависимости от числительных?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Написал метод, способный определять правильное окончание у существительных множественного числа в зависимости от числительного. Кратко говоря, если мы хотим вывести текст

```
 342 книги
```

То нужно сделать так

```
System.out.print(fixNumerical(342, "книга", "книги", "книг"));
```

Сам метод

```
public static String fixNumerical (int num, String... arr)
{
    String result = null;
    if(num == 11) result = arr[2];
    else if(("" + num).endsWith("1")) result = arr[0];
    else if(num > 11 && num < 15) result = arr[2];
    else if(num % 10 > 1 && num % 10 < 5) result = arr[1];
    else result = arr[2];
    return result;
}
```

Я протестировал, вроде работает хорошо, но как его можно улучшить, может быть, что-то все-таки не соблюдено? И еще название метода не посоветуете поадекватнее?

Comment: Если под андроид, то там есть `plurals` - встроенная хрень под все языки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, под javа, под java, чистая java :)

Comment: Может тут чего интересного найдёте: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне бы услышать критику кода)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 11-15 надо проверять для каждой сотни. Т.е. нужен остаток от деления на 100.
2. Первое и третье условие легко объединить.
3. Во втором условии можно использовать остаток от деления на 10, как в четвёртом условии.
4. Первым делом можно проверять не от 11 до 15, а от 5 до 20. Тогда 5-20 в каждой сотне не будут долетать до следующих проверок, и для них алгоритм закончится раньше.

Тогда блок проверок получится таким:

```
if(num % 100 > 4 && num % 100 < 21) result = arr[2];
else if(num % 10 == 1) result = arr[0];
else if(num % 10 > 1 && num % 10 < 5) result = arr[1];
else result = arr[2];
```

Ещё остатки от деления на 100 и на 10 можно считать один раз, сохраняя в переменных. Тогда так:

```
int num100 = num % 100;
if(num100 > 4 && num100 < 21) result = arr[2];
else {
    int num10 = num100 % 10;
    if(num10 == 1) result = arr[0];
    else if(num10 > 1 && num10 < 5) result = arr[1];
    else result = arr[2];
}
```

Comment: Думаю, актуально. Ведь нужно, вроде как, избегать дублирования

Comment: @Flippy Добавил вариант с переменными. Но с джавой не работал, перепроверьте мой синтаксис.

Comment: @Flippy И первой проверкой можно охватить ещё более широкий диапазон - от 5 до 20. Отредактировал ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим по **предпоследней** цифре: если 1 - `книг` иначе по **последней** цифре: 1 - `книга`, 2-4 - `книги`, остальное - `книг`.

```
public static String fixNumerical (int num, String... arr)
{
    Integer preLastDigit = num % 100 / 10;
    if (preLastDigit == 1) {
        return String.format("%d %s", num, arr[2]);
    }

    Integer lastDigit = num % 10;
    switch (lastDigit) {
        case 1:
            return String.format("%d %s", num, arr[0]);
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return String.format("%d %s", num, arr[1]);
        default:
            return String.format("%d %s", num, arr[2]);
    }
}
```

[Тестить](https://ideone.com/wjfs2R)!